# SnapLogic join snap not returning results

Tags: snaplogic

I am new to SnapLogic and I am using the join snap but for some reason, it doesn’t find any matches but I know there are matches. I have outputted both streams to a file and I confirmed that they have matching IDs but when the join snap runs it doesn’t return any results. This is an inner join.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the **Sorted streams** setting in your **Join** snap.

This setting asks how the incoming data is sorted. Options available are -

- Ascending
- Descending
- Unsorted

If an Unsorted data stream is selected, the Snap sorts input data streams before it starts the join operation.

The default value for this setting is **Ascending**. So, if you are passing unsorted streams of data and the Sorted streams setting has the default value Ascending, then your pipeline won't be able to join the data.

Refer to: [Join - SnapLogic Documentation](https://docs-snaplogic.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SD/pages/1439005/Join)